# Having YouTube play a random video from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, youtube-api

How would I be able to have this work in the code?

or for this to be able to work in the code, would it be written differently?

```
var videos = [
    '0dgNc5S8cLI',
    'mnfmQe8Mv1g',
    'CHahce95B1g'
];

var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
```

How the code is set up is that, you click on the cover which opens a video.

https://jsfiddle.net/e4bg537p/

How would I be able to set it up so that it plays 1 random video from an array of YouTube ids?

That is what I am trying to figure out how to do.

Can someone show me how this would be done?

```
<div class="video video-frame" data-id="-SiGnAi845o"></div>

    (function manageCover() {

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function hide(el) {
        el.classList.add("hide");
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const cover = evt.currentTarget;
        hide(cover);
        const video = cover.parentElement.querySelector(".wrap");
        show(video);
    }

    const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

    let player = null;

    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player = event.target;
        player.setVolume(100); // percent
    }

    function addPlayer(video) {

        const config = {
            height: 360,
            host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
            videoId: video.dataset.id,
            width: 640
        };
        config.playerVars = {
            autoplay: 0,
            cc_load_policy: 0,
            controls: 1,
            disablekb: 1,
            fs: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            rel: 0
        };
        config.events = {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady
        };
        player = new YT.Player(video, config);

    }

    function play() {
        player.playVideo();
    }
    return {
        addPlayer,
        play
    };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
    const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
    const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
    videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
}

(function initCover() {

    function coverClickHandler() {
        videoPlayer.play();
    }

    const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function that initializes the `data-id` attribute of the video frame, before the rest of the scripts fire:

```js
(function init(){
    var videos = [
        '0dgNc5S8cLI',
        'mnfmQe8Mv1g',
        'CHahce95B1g'
   ];
   var v = videos[Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length)];
   document.querySelector('.video.video-frame').setAttribute('data-id', v);
}());

(function manageCover() {
    //...
})
```

Comment: What did I do wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/xo41gsnk/ There's an error somewhere.

Comment: @htmlcssjavascript5436 What's the problem? It seems to pick a random video every time you re-run the Fiddle. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: It says misleading linebreak in the code. How is that fixed? When I click on the cover it's not opening. Can you show me it working in the jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't see that error, and when I click on the cover the video plays.

Comment: Yes it's what I want, but there's an error in it that I can't figure out how to fix.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. I've revised my answer so that warning should disappear now.

Comment: @learningtocode435 Just in case you didn't know, in this particular instance `Math.floor` can be replaced with `~~`. It's negligibly faster and shorter 

Answer (score 0):

*[EDIT] misunderstood the question...this method is if you want it continue playing random videos...*

One method is to use `onStateChange` event:

https://jsfiddle.net/vanowm/14q05ozd/

```
var videos = [
    '0dgNc5S8cLI',
    'mnfmQe8Mv1g',
    'CHahce95B1g'
];
var videosRand = [];

    function addPlayer(video) {

        function onStateChange(e)
        {
          if (e.data)
            return;

          //copy list of videos and remove last played id so it doesn't play again
          if (!videosRand.length)
            videosRand = videos.filter(a => a != player.getVideoData().video_id);

          //get random index and remove the id from the array
          const id = videosRand.splice(~~(Math.random() * videosRand.length), 1)[0];
console.log(id);
          player.loadVideoById(id);
        }
        const config = {
            height: 360,
            host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
            videoId: video.dataset.id,
            width: 640
        };
        config.playerVars = {
            autoplay: 0,
            cc_load_policy: 0,
            controls: 1,
            disablekb: 1,
            fs: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            rel: 0
        };
        config.events = {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady,
            "onStateChange": onStateChange
        };
        player = new YT.Player(video, config);

    }
```

Comment: How would I replace the arrow function in your code with a regular function?

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: I'm doing this wrong: filter(function(a  != player.getVideoData()

Comment: what's wrong with arrow functions? `videosRand = videos.filter(function(a){return a != player.getVideoData().video_id});`

Comment: Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'.
                return; //////////////   How is that fixed in your code? //////    function onStateChange(e) {
            if (e.data)
                return;   /////// Image: https://i.imgur.com/dr5k7iW.png

Comment: How would that be fixed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Fix what? As you can se the code runs fine at the jsfiddle. Whatever is complaining maybe doesn't like not having `if` statement enclosed into curly brackets, so just enclose it like so: `{ return; }`

Comment: http://linterrors.com/js/option-jshint-curly (and I've updated my previous comment)

Comment: And this is the last one. https://i.imgur.com/giUofKN.png  How is the one fixed?

Comment: Pretty much the same: `{ videosRand = videos.filter(a => a != player.getVideoData().video_id); }`. But if I were you, I'd rather fix the jslint configuration instead...these "errors" are perfectly acceptable javascript code. If you are planning on continue to code in JS, this will save you from a lot of unnecessary headache like this.

Comment: {  videoList = videos.filter(function (a) { return a != player.getVideoData().video_id);   ////// Expected ';' and instead saw ')'.

Comment: This is wrong: { videosRand = videos.filter(a => a != player.getVideoData().video_id); } ///////

Comment: Expected ';' and instead saw '}'.  ///////
            });}

Comment: What should this be?            {videoList = videos.filter(function (a) {
                return a != player.getVideoData().video_id
            }};

Comment: The end tag is wrong.  }}; What does it need to be changed to?

Comment: You almost got it, just missing `)` in there ;)

Comment: Expected ';' and instead saw '}'.   ////// What is wrong here?
            }};)

Comment: What has to be fixed here? ///// {videoList = videos.filter(function (a) {
                return a != player.getVideoData().video_id }};)

Comment: Well, first you need to understand what changes are made in both example and merge them together. You have all the information you need. Good luck

Comment: I got it:             {videoList = videos.filter(function (a) {
                return a !== player.getVideoData().video_id ;});}

Comment: I have a question, how come you only used "~~" once in your code and not twice? You didn't add it here: var index=Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);/// How come you didn't add it to the 1st one?

Comment: That is your line, not mine. I only added my code, didn't change/remove yours ;) That line is redundant and be deleted.